# VS 2013 Release Management - Illegal characters in path

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I have build a custom deployment Action based on TFS 2010 command-line utility, TF.exe. When executed from a DOS prompt on the deployment agent server, it runs fine.

```
TF view /collection:uri "$source path" > "local path"
```

and the file does get downloaded, without a need of a workspace. However, when executed through VS2013RM, I get an error:

```
Illegal characters in path.
```

When I hover over the message column it reads:

```
The installation command \"my correct command line here\" failed with the exit code \"100\"
```

What gives? How come it executes fine in one place, but not the other? The RM Client runs under a network service account, which is part of the local admins and collection's service accounts.

**After enabling log**

I was able to capture this command:

```
Deployment: **********Installing component using command "C:\DevOps\TfsClient\TF.exe view /collection:http://[removed detail] "$/[removed detail]/MetastoreCS.xml" > "F:\[removed detail]\MetastoreCS.xml""
```

Than the error

```
9/24/2014 10:58:10 AM - Information - (12628, 26560) - Deployment: Exception The installation  command \"C:\DevOps\TfsClient\TF.exe view /collection:http://[removed detail] "$/[removed detail]/MetastoreCS.xml" > "F:\[removed detail]\MetastoreCS.xml"\" failed with the exit code \"100\".
```

Comment: is it the quotes around source path etc? and aren't you using a different version of TF if you run from VS2013?

Comment: Quotes in place, same version of TF"

Comment: Enable the logs on the Agent side and give us the actual command executed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/13/how-to-enable-detailed-logs-and-collect-traces-from-various-release-management-components.aspx

Comment: @Darek I meant is it the double-quotes, what happens if you use singles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the redirecting character '>' is causing issue.

I was able to make it work using the `/output` option. Refer to the [tf view documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxk6367(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
C:\DevOps\TfsClient\TF.exe view /collection:http://[removed detail] "$/[removed detail]/MetastoreCS.xml" /output:"F:\[removed detail]\MetastoreCS.xml"
```

Comment: It should be /output:"[File Name]", but the solution works. For some reason in the past I thought I have encountered a need for creating a workspace, which would be a big no-no, but this time around it worked. One thing to keep in mind, if you change the Tool's definition, you must abandon the prior rejected release. Otherwise the old command will be used.

Comment: I made the adjustment. Note also that you don't have to abandon the rejected release. As long as you create a new Release, you will be good.

Comment: Meaning existing releases are not affected by changes to tools, actions, components, release templates. A release is a snapshot in time of your configuration elements.

Comment: Right, what I meant was you cannot restart a rejected release. That will fail.